# "Times" font on Mac's font book is missing

Tags: mac, fonts, microsoft-onenote, ios

I am using Times font on one note Mac.
but could not find the same font "Times" on iPad.
so I tried to find it on the Mac's Font book so I can install this same font on iPad too. but there is no font called "Times"
I want to find this font. please help

**Note:** Times font is different from Times new roman due to line spacing, otherwise both are same.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Restoring the standard fonts moves any fonts you've installed into a separate folder, which makes them unavailable to use in apps. In the Font Book app on your Mac, choose Font Book > Settings. Click Advanced, then click Reset Fonts. Click Proceed to confirm, and enter your password if asked (or use Touch ID).

Comment: didnt work for me :(